# Laravel: How to use Gates with multiple Guards

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a traditional web application that has a number of different user types, and each user type has its own Authentication guard.

```
'guards' => [

    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admin',
    ],
    'timekeeper' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'timekeeper',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Most my users authenticate using the 'web' guard, however administrators and timekeepers each use their own guard, which is attached to an appropriate user provider.

This is fine until I try to use authentication gates.  If I authenticate a user against the system's default guard (e.g. 'web'), then the gates work as expected.  If I authenticate against any other guard however, then all `Gate::allows(...)` calls are DENIED.

Even the following ability is denied:

```
Gate::define('read', function ($user) {
    return true;
});
```

Presumably this is due to line 284-286 in Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate:

```
if (! $user = $this->resolveUser()) {
    return false;
}
```

As far as I can see, my options are to:

- Go back to using a single 'web' guard, with a user provider that can locate any type of user (but I'm not sure how that would work if I start using an API in parallel)
- Somehow set the default guard at run time, depending on the type of the current user.  (It is currently set in the config file)
- Somehow inject a different user resolver in to the Gate facade (again, depending on the type of the current user)

None of these seems intuitive however.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not the most elegant solution because it requires a lot of extra boilerplate code, but you can use `Gate::forUser($user)->allows()` instead of just `Gate::allows()` where `$user` comes from `Auth::guard()`.

Comment: Working from this answer, I implemented a helper function to reduce the boilerplate and am satisfied with the result.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I didn't really like this solution. After quite a lot of research I came up with this way to make your own user resolver in the Gate:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton(GateContract::class, function ($app) {
        return new \Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate($app, function () use($app) {

            $user = call_user_func($app['auth']->userResolver());

            if (is_null($user)) {
                // Implement your own logic for resolving the user
            }

            return $user;
        });
    });
}
```

I put this in my `AuthServiceProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

set $user to null

```php
Gate::define('read', function ($user = null) {
    return true;
});
```